# How do I stay ahead with the latest WebDriver version on Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-jupiter

Since the browser update yesterday my test won't start and I get the message:

```
There was an error creating WebDriver object for Chrome
```

I use Selenium Jupiter with the @TestTemplate and my browsers.json looks:

```
{
  "browsers": [
    [
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "version": "latest"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.14.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I thought that the webdrivermanager would solve that version issues.
My experience with Selenium is not so huge, because I use that only for a few weeks.

Is there a solution to keep up with the latest browser versions?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 4.14 has built in [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/). Just remove the `webdrivermanager` dependency

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: In your case I can only test with one browser.

Comment: @ladida It's just an example, all the browsers are using this ability.

Comment: Yes, but on the long run I want to test with multiple browsers. Like I understood I have to use selenium jupiter with browser.json for that. But idk. I'm a selenium noob.
My problem was that I hadn't installed chrome (I use chromium and that works until now).